# What are the units when we compute a derivative of a scalar field relative to a non-unit vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In chapter 8 of Apostol's *Calculus Volume II*, there is the definition of the derivative of a scalar field with respect to a vector.

> Given a scalar field $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$, where
> $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\vec{a}$ be an interior point of $S$
> and let $\vec{y}$ be an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The
> derivative of $f$ at $\vec{a}$ with respect to $\vec{y}$ is denoted
> $f'(\vec{a};\vec{y})$ and is defined by the equation
>
> $$f'(\vec{a};\vec{y})=\lim\limits_{h\to
> > 0}\frac{f(\vec{a}+h\vec{y})-f(\vec{a})}{h}\tag{1}$$
>
> when the limit on the right exists.

**Let's consider an example in one dimension.**

Let $s(t)=t^2$, let our point $\vec{a}$ be the origin, and let our vector $\vec{y}$ be any real number.

First, consider the just the expression (without the limit)

$$\frac{s(t+nh)-s(t)}{h}=\frac{(t+nh)^2-t^2}{h}\tag{2}$$

$$=\frac{2tnh-n^2h^2}{h}\tag{3}$$

If $n=2$ and $h=1$ then we have

$$\frac{s(0+2\cdot 1)}{1}=4\tag{4}$$

What does this mean?

When time increases by 2 seconds, position changes by 4 meters.

We get the average rate of change between times $0$ and $2$ per change of two seconds.

Now, the units were driving me crazy. Until I reached the interpretation below, I rewrote this question multiple times and here I am two hours later. **My question is essentially if the reasoning below answers the title question that I have asked.**

Let's call a period of time relative to which we are computing change in position a "block".

Then the units of $n$ are seconds/block, and the unit of $h$ is blocks.

Thus we have

$$\frac{s(\mathrm{0s+2 \frac{s}{block}\cdot 1 block})}{1 \text{block}}=4 \mathrm{\frac{m}{block}}\tag{4}$$

Now let $h=0.5$.

$$\frac{s(\mathrm{0s+2 \frac{s}{block}\cdot 0.5 block})}{0.5 \text{block}}=2 \mathrm{\frac{m}{block}}\tag{5}$$

Why is (5) less than (4)? In (5) we take the change from 0s to 1s and say it is half the block of time we want. Therefore, to to get the block we want, we double the change.

Similarly, in (4) we take the change from 0s to 2s and say it is one block.

The change in 2s is larger than two times the change in the first second.

The main point is that the result when doing this type of calculation is always a rate of change relative to the block of time we are using.

If the reasoning above is correct, then it is also correct for a scalar field with a domain of a higher dimension. After all, the reasoning applies to each of the arguments of such a function $f$ that appears in expression (1). In generic terms the units of each argument of an expression like $f(\vec{x}+h\vec{y})$ would be something like the following

$$\mathrm{x\ unit_1 + y\ \frac{unit_1}{block}\cdot h\ block}\tag{6}$$

$$=(x+yh)\ \mathrm{unit_1}\tag{7}$$

where $\mathrm{unit_1}$ can be any units.

The "block" in the multivariable case is not a number but a vector, so if we have a function $f$ with units $\mathrm{unit_2}$, then the final units will be

$$\mathrm{\frac{unit_2}{block}}$$

where block is a vector. Ie, we get change in function when we change the vector (which is the change in the input to the function) by one block.

My conclusion with all of this is that when we are computing a derivative relative to a vector, we are computing a rate of change relative to a change of input equal to the vector (which in the multivariable case is our "block").

**Here is an example:**

$T(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is temperature on a 2d grid.

Let $\vec{v}=\langle 2,0 \rangle$.

Let's compute the derivative of $T$ at $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ with respect to  $\vec{v}$.

We have

$$\frac{T\left (\langle 1,1 \rangle\ \text{m} +h\ \text{block}\cdot \langle 2,0 \rangle \mathrm{\frac{m}{block}}\right )-T\left (\langle 1,1 \rangle\ \text{m}\right )}{h\ \text{block}}$$

$$=\frac{T\left ( \langle 1+2h,1 \rangle \text{m} \right )-T\left ( \langle 1,1\rangle\ \text{m} \right )}{h\ \text{block}}$$

$$=\frac{(1+2h)^2+1^2-(1^2+1^2)}{h} \mathrm{\frac{K}{block}}$$

$$=(4+4h) \mathrm{\frac{K}{block}}$$

which means that if $h=1$, for example, we are moving from $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ to $\langle 3,1 \rangle$ and the change in $T$ is 8K.

If we convert to $K/m$ then we get

$$8\frac{K}{block}\cdot \langle 0.5, 0 \rangle \frac{block}{m}$$

$$=\langle 4,0 \rangle \frac{K}{m}$$

which is the average rate of change per meter when we move from $\langle 1,1 \rangle$ to $\langle 3,1 \rangle$.

Comment: If $h$ is just a number with no units, then how can the units of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ be units of a rate of change? That is, if there are no units in the denominator, then the rate of change of the numerator is relative to what?

Answer (score 1):

From Apostol's definition it immediately follows that $h\vec y$ must have the same dimension as $\vec a$. To connect with the usual concept of differentiation, we must assume that $h$ has the same dimension as $\vec a$ whereas $\vec y$ is a dimensionless vector.

Let us say we work in two dimensional space. We can take $\vec y = (1,0)$. What we get is the derivative of $f$ in the point $\vec a$ in the $x$-direction. When we take $\vec y= (0,1)$ we obtain the derivative of $f$ in the point $\vec a$ in the $y$-direction. In the general case, where $\vec y = (y_{1}, y_{2})$, the deriviative is given by $y_{1}f_{x} + y_{2}f_{y}$. In other words, Apostol's derivative gives the inner product between the vector $\vec y$ and the gradient of the function $f$:

$$f'(\vec a; \vec y) = \vec y \cdot \nabla f(\vec a)$$